# Duda de Concepto de clases en python

Tags: python, class

Estoy comenzando a aprender programación en Python con un curso en Udemy. Estamos viendo el siguiente ejercicio sobre herencias, pero VS Code me da un problema. ¿Está escrito correctamente? ¿Existe alguna forma de mejorar el código?

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, nombre, onomatopeya,):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.onomatopeya = onomatopeya
    def saludo(self):
        print("Hola, soy un", self.tipo, "y hago", self.onomatopeya)
        print("Me llamo", self.nombre)

class Gato(Animal):
    tipo = "gato"

class Perro(Animal):
    tipo = "perro"

gato = Gato("Fluffy", "Miau")
gato.saludo()

perro = Perro("Firulais", "Guau")
perro.saludo()
```

> El problema: "Instace of 'Animal' has no 'tipo' member" [6, 31]

Cualquier consejo para mejorar o recursos de donde aprender son bienvenidos. Graciaas!

Comment: El código que proporcionas es correcto y no da ningún error. Parece que te dejaste fuera la parte del código que genera el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que has puesto ejecutará sin errores en este caso, debido a que los objetos `perro` y `gato` pueden acceder al atributo `tipo` de sus clases (`Perro` y `Gato` respectivamente).

Sin embargo observa que nada te impide instanciar directamente la clase `Animal`, con algo como lo siguiente:

```
animal = Animal("Catoblepas", "Fgrrgh")
animal.saludo()
```

En este caso sí que tendrás un error cuando se intente acceder a  `self.tipo` ya que la clase `Animal` no tiene ese atributo, y el objeto instanciado (`animal`) tampoco lo tiene porque no se le da un valor en el constructor.

Por tanto, conceptualmente sí que podría decirse que tu código **es erróneo** aunque en este ejemplo particular pueda ejecutar sin errores.

Ya que la clase `Animal` hace uso de un campo `self.tipo` sería más correcto que inicializara ese campo, ya sea como atributo de clase o como atributo de objeto. Ya que en tu caso quieres que clases derivadas (`Perro`, `Gato`...) puedan cambiar el valor del atributo de clase, lo correcto sería tener ese atributo de clase también en `Animal`.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Animal:
    tipo = "animal"
    # El resto igual a como lo tenías
```

De este modo, la creación de un `Animal` "a secas" funcionaría también.

Si en cambio quieres provocar un error cuando se intente instanciar un `Animal` a secas, podrías hacer uso de un truco como el siguiente:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, nombre, onomatopeya):
        if self.__class__ == Animal:
          raise TypeError("No se puede instanciar directamente la clase Animal")
        # El resto igual
```

Con esto se impide que se instancie un `Animal`. Si lo intentas te producirá la excepción `TypeError`.

Comment: Era un ejercicio de herencia así que debíamos no poner el **tipo** como instancia de  **Animal**, ese truco de **TypeError** es muy util. Además he comprendido mejor como funcionan las clases. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje

```
Instace of 'Animal' has no 'tipo' member" [6, 31]
```

es la mitad de la verdad.

Efectivamente, los objetos de tipo `Animal` (y subclases) no tienen una *variable de instancia* llamada `tipo`. Sin embargo, `Gato` y `Perro` definen una *variable de clase* ese nombre.

Las variables de clase son compartidas por todos los objetos de esa clase. Si instancias una jauría de `Perros`, sólo habrá una variable `tipo` compartida entre todos.

Sin embargo, ambas variables (de instancia y de clase) son referenciadas de la misma forma:

```
nombre_objeto.nombre_variable
```

Por ejemplo, en la línea:

```
print("Hola, soy un", self.tipo, "y hago", self.onomatopeya)
```

referencias una varible de clase (`self.tipo`) y una de instancia (`self.onomatopeya`) usando la misma sintaxis.

¿Por qué te marca error? Porque el intérprete tiene una visión incompleta del programa. El programa en definitiva viene a existir cuando lo ejecutas. En ese momento se crean las variables y todo funciona.